# Orbits of Saturn's moons inside its rings

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, newtonian-gravity, orbital-motion, solar-system, satellites

Hypothetically speaking if a solid  artificial satellite is injected into one of Saturn's rings, what natural Newtonian orbit does it take?

Is  gravity force modelling of dust particle orbit done? Is the orbit always circular with no radial velocity component? If elliptic orbits do exist, are time periods and eccentricities of some prominent ones at least been so far computed or observed from Cassini spacecraft?

EDIT1

First let us assume a radial insertion velocity one half of $\sqrt{ G M_{saturn}/ {R_{saturn} }} $ irrespective of how the mass can be injected. Secondly how does one model attraction of gravity in a distributed mass system containing injected satellite mass? Is there a group velocity without shear effect of dust on the lumped mass? I am clueless about the big picture.

Comment: First of all, what are the details of the injection? This will largely determine the orbit. Second, are you asking whether the presence of the rings affects the orbit? Third, I'm confused about what you mean by "if elliptic orbits do exist"?

Comment: Edited as above